# How do I make a menu search bar for two lists?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a list of songs I listen from time to time and it will probably become big soon so I was trying to make a search bar to be easier to find them but the most tutorials don't really help and the closest I found was [this.  (W3Schools - How TO - Search Menu)](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_search_menu.asp)

Here is a smaller version:

```html
<ul style="border: 0.05cm solid whitesmoke; width: 40%; float: left; background-image: url(ah_strip_offic_pap.png); color: whitesmoke;">

  <li>PRINCESS QUEST
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Follow You</a> - Kyle Allen Music</li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">You're the Key</a> - Kyle Allen Music</li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a> - Kyle Allen Music</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>HAYLOFT
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Hayloft</a> - Mother Mother</li>
      <li><a href="#">Hayloft II</a> - Mother Mother</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>WELCOME HOME
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Welcome Home</a> - Hailey Lain
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">(Remastered)</a> - Hailey Lain</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Behind the Curtain</a> - Hailey Lain</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>WOLVES
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Wolves</a> - NightCove_theFox</li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Far Too Long</a> - NightCove_theFox</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul style="border: 0.05cm solid whitesmoke; width: 40%; float: right; background-image: url(ah_strip_offic_pap.png); color: whitesmoke;">
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Love Taste</a> - Moe Shop
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">(Remix)</a> - SadeN</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">S.O.S (Source of Savagery)</a> - SharaX</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">world.execute(me);</a> - MILI</li>
  <li><a href="#">A Songus Amongus</a> - The Chalkeaters</li>
  <li><a href="#">My Time</a> - bo en</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Secrets of Wysteria</a> - Steampianist
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">(Reversed Ver.)</a> - Steampianist</li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">(Cover)</a> - Lizz Robinett</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Hidden in the Sand</a> - Tally Hall</li>
  <li><a href="#">You Can't Hide</a> - CK9C</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Love Me, Love Me, Love Me</a> - kikuo
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">(English Cover)</a> - LittleJayneyCake</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">As Above So Below</a> - KMODO</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Isn't this Enough?</a> - xXtha</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Kiss Me (Kill Me)</a> - JerryTerry</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what your using which programming ?

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you tried to write your search functionality? Do you have any code, so that we can help you understand the mistake(s) in order that you, and future visitors to this question, can learn from them, and see how to implement a search function? Were there any specific problems you encountered, did something go wrong (and how?) or were there errors generated (what were the errors?)?

Comment: @DavidThomas 1) Where did you get stuck when you tried to write your search functionality? - To make it work on both lists instend on just one,
it was showing result only based on the part that was clickable with a link (only the songs and not the artist sins i didn't make that part clickable so i can tell them apart)
and to make it not hide the links that were conected (like covers and remixes).

Comment: 2) Do you have any code, so that we can help you understand the mistake(s) in order that you, and future visitors to this question, can learn from them, and see how to implement a search function? - I didn't save it sins it didn't work properly and it was based on the link that I put in the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this:

```
<input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
<ul style="border: 0.05cm solid whitesmoke; width: 40%; float: left; background-image: url(ah_strip_offic_pap.png); color: whitesmoke;">

  <li>PRINCESS QUEST
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Follow You</a> - Kyle Allen Music</li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">You're the Key</a> - Kyle Allen Music</li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a> - Kyle Allen Music</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>HAYLOFT
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Hayloft</a> - Mother Mother</li>
      <li><a href="#">Hayloft II</a> - Mother Mother</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>WELCOME HOME
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Welcome Home</a> - Hailey Lain
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">(Remastered)</a> - Hailey Lain</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Behind the Curtain</a> - Hailey Lain</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>WOLVES
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Wolves</a> - NightCove_theFox</li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Far Too Long</a> - NightCove_theFox</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul style="border: 0.05cm solid whitesmoke; width: 40%; float: right; background-image: url(ah_strip_offic_pap.png); color: whitesmoke;">
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Love Taste</a> - Moe Shop
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">(Remix)</a> - SadeN</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">S.O.S (Source of Savagery)</a> - SharaX</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">world.execute(me);</a> - MILI</li>
  <li><a href="#">A Songus Amongus</a> - The Chalkeaters</li>
  <li><a href="#">My Time</a> - bo en</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Secrets of Wysteria</a> - Steampianist
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">(Reversed Ver.)</a> - Steampianist</li>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">(Cover)</a> - Lizz Robinett</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Hidden in the Sand</a> - Tally Hall</li>
  <li><a href="#">You Can't Hide</a> - CK9C</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Love Me, Love Me, Love Me</a> - kikuo
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">(English Cover)</a> - LittleJayneyCake</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">As Above So Below</a> - KMODO</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Isn't this Enough?</a> - xXtha</li>
  <li><a href="#" style="color: springgreen;">Kiss Me (Kill Me)</a> - JerryTerry</li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Variable `li` is an array of all elements with tag `<li>`.
For each element in `li`, the loop checks whether it matches the input field value or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Dion06 Next time you ask a question, please provide full code directly rather that telling that you found this tutorial and trying to do like that.